# How to remove a network?

Tags: networking, rhel, network-interface

I have 3 networks under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` on RHEL:

```
ifcfg-lan0 ifcfg-lan1 ifcfg-lo
```

`ip a` will list these informations:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    ....
2: lan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    ....
3: lan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    ....
```

I want to delete `lan1`.

I removed `ifcfg-lan1` under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

Run `$ sudo ip link delete lan1` got:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

Restart network service

```
sudo systemctl restart network
```

Restarted system then got:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    ....
2: lan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    ....
3: lan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    ....
```

How to remove `lan1`?

Comment: Is this a VM or a physical server?

Comment: @NasirRiley It's a VM.

Comment: Is it vSphere/Vcenter? Are there two virtual network adapters in the VM's settings?

Comment: It's created by OpenStack. Yes, there are 2 virtual network defined in the heat template. Then use it created the stack.

Comment: Power off the VM, remove the network adapter for lan1, and then power it back on.

Comment: `remove the network adapter for lan1` Where to operate it?

Comment: As it's OpenStack, put in a support ticket to remove the virtual network adapter for lan1.

Comment: @NasirRiley Do you mean let administrator to do it? Do you know how to do it technically?

Comment: I've never used OpenStack before, so no. If you put in a support case with them, I'm sure that a technician will walk you through it or do it for you.

Comment: OK, thank you all the same.